# How to install and use Openmp in vs code

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, openmp

I have install and run correctly c/c++ in vscode, my gcc version is 8.2.0 and I have installed MinGw

I use VS code to run my C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int nthreads, tid;
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("welcome to GFG from thread = %d\n", tid);
        if (tid == 0){
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            printf("number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't work because

```
[Running] cd "c:\cexam\" && gcc openmp_helloword.c -o openmp_helloword && "c:\cexam\"openmp_helloword
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WinstonLi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAAWXl3.o:openmp_helloword.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WinstonLi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAAWXl3.o:openmp_helloword.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> gcc openmp_helloword.c -o openmp_helloword

You are missing libraries during link.  gcc will add them for you with `-fopenmp`.  Consider the documentation:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-fopenmp

Comment: I run your code in VS' terminal, but it show gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: What he wants to say is that in the end of your g++ build command, you have to add a `-fopenmp` argument

Answer (score 4):

in my tasks.json I added the line: "-fopenmp",
under args, like this:

```
...

"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "W:\\Programs\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-fopenmp",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],


...
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable `openmp` in vs code options.

Right-click on your project, select "properties", then C/C++, then Language, and change “OpenMP Support” to ‘Yes’.

It should add the option `-fopenmp` to the compilation options.

Comment: I cannot find properties when I right click my project, there are only open editor, outline. On the internet, it said that open default setting.json and change "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": to true but the problem is I cannot rewrite it! why?

Comment: this is for visual studio not for visual studio code